# Restarting a Java program does not work with the new JDK 21.02_13

Tags: java, jpackage

my Java app experienced a very weird regression when switching from JDK
OpenJDK21U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_21.0.1_12
to
OpenJDK21U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_21.0.2_13

This small snippet should start a third party software (in this case Notepad++.exe but it's just an example) and after 30 seconds, close the java app that launched it.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String[] cmdToRunUsingArgs = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"};
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdToRunUsingArgs);
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(() -> {
            System.exit(0);
        }, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

It works well with all previous JDK versions but it stopped working from java 21.0.2 and later.

With JDK 21.0.1, the program launches the third party app correcly, after 30 seconds, it kills itself by leaving the third app running.
With JDK 21.0.2, the program launches the third party app correcly, after 30 seconds, it kills itself AND the third party app.

this makes even impossible to restart a java app from the app itself.

The problems happens if you create the exe file with JPackage and then you launch the program using the exe file,
if you run the jar file with java -jar does not occur.

Any idea why the new JDK introduced this regression?

#### Expected Results

Program should start the third party app and then close itself after 30 seconds by leaving the third party app running.

#### Actual Results

Program start the third party app but after 30 seconds it kills both the third party app and itself.

Comment: You should try to read the output and error stream, to see if there is any output there

Comment: I can reproduce, the EXE wrapper produced by jpackage appears to clean up the sub-process on exit.

Comment: Can also reproduce (even when starting the third-party executable directly instead of via CMD).

Comment: Expected results in JDK17 jpackage, same as Actual results in JDK22, so perhaps you should be looking at raising in JDK bug database

Comment: Note that you should be able to workaround the problem by launching jpackage of the previous JDK21 you use. If you need EXE to use the later JDK21.0.2 runtime you can use jlink and make the older jpackage generate exes with the newer runtime - `JDK21/bin/jpackage" --runtime-image yourjre21.0.2`

Comment: Ok, it is confirmed that it is a jpackage bug. I submitted a bug report and Oracle accepted it as a P3 bug.
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8325203

Comment: When [comparing jdk-21.0.1-ga to jdk-21.0.2-ga](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk21u/compare/jdk-21.0.1-ga...jdk-21.0.2-ga), the only changes that seem relevant are part of the fix for [JDK-8301247](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8301247) (a bug linked in a comment to the issue you submitted). The changes included adding the use of [job objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) configured to terminate associated processes.

Comment: Also related to handling of sub-processes and [JDK-8301247](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75173536/jpackage-app-image-exe-launches-multiple-exes-in-jdk-17).